# Let p<q both be prime numbers. Prove that log is not rational number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

So i was given a question that starts off like this

Prove that $\log_q(p)$ is not a rational number.

- Recall that $\log_y(x)$ for real numbers $x,y>0$ is defined to be the real number $r$ so that $y^r = x$.

So in this question, in other words,  $\log_q(p)$ will be the real number which, when you raise $q$ to it, you get $p$.

I was told that i should turn $\log_q(p)$ into an expression involving an integer power of $q$ and an integer power of $p$, and use the Uniqueness of Prime Factorization, but i do not know how to use it.

Comment: Are you clear on the first step?  You seem to say it words, that $r = \log_q p$ means $q^r = p$.  Start there and clear the denominator of exponent $r$ by raising both sides to the same integer power.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\log_{q}(p)=a/b$. Then $p=q^{a/b}$, so $p^{b}=q^{a}$. Can you do it from here?

Comment: Oh i see thanks